# Finishing current activity closes entire app

Tags: android, android-activity

I am sending notifications through firebase and when I receive a notification, I am opening an activity with that notification data, activity opens like a popup reminder which has a close button, pressing it should close this current app and stays where it is in current history stack, Suppose I am inside any screen and notification comes from back-end and that popup activity opens and on clicking on close button it should only close that particular activity, not the entire application which is happening in current scenario. I have also added noHistory tag to true in manifest.
//opening activity from firebase messaging service

```
public void openGifActivity(String alarmType, String message, String extraMessage, String gifUrl, String leadNumber, String followUpTime, String userName) {

        Intent intentGIFActivity = new Intent(this, AlarmGIFActivity.class);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("alarmType", alarmType);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("gifMessage", message);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("extraMessage", extraMessage);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("gifUrl", gifUrl);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("followUpTime", followUpTime);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("leadNumber", leadNumber);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("userName", userName);
        intentGIFActivity.putExtra("message", "0");
        startActivity(intentGIFActivity);
    }
```

//closing this activity on button click

```
close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
                    mMediaPlayer.stop();
                }
                if (vibrator != null) {
                    vibrator.cancel();

                }
                AlarmGIFActivity.this.finish();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Create this `Activity` in separate `ActivityStack`. Try to se `NEW_TASK` flag when creating `Intent`.

Comment: I am also opening this activity from another activity, in that case, it works just fine, when I open this activity from firebaseMessagingService, in that case, it does not work. Maybe it has a problem with the context being passed while creating intent.

Answer (score 0):

After this AlarmGIFActivity.this.finish(). Start your DesiredActivity which you want to navigate in. dont miss to set flags for new task & clear task.

```
 intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

Comment: That I already know, But my purpose is not that, I don't know at that time which fragment(I am using fragments) was on top, because this AlarmGifActivity is like a popup which comes when a new notification arrives and should close on clicking close button , rest of the app should remain same